# Searching for capital letters within a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find all of the capital letters within a string, and output what that characters element in the array is. For example:

```
"PiE" would have an out put of [0, 2]
```

What I have noticed is that if there were two of the same capital letters, is would show as the same elements. i.e:

```
"HaH" has an output of [0,0]
```

Here is my code this far:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^[A-Z\d]+$')
elemList = []

def capitals(word):
    pattern.match(word)
    for w in word:
        if w != w.lower():
            a = word.index(w)
            elemList.append(a)
    return elemList
```

Thanks, guys!

Comment: just use `[i for i, c in enumerate(word) if c.islower()]`. As you found out, `.index` gives you the *first* index in the string that matches the argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension here. How's this?

`elemList = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.isupper()]`

Here it is in a repl:

```
>>> def find_capitals(word):
...     return [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.isupper()]
...
>>> find_capitals('PiE')
[0, 2]
>>> find_capitals('HaHaHa')
[0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be a straight forward approach using "normal" programming concepts:

```
def getUpperPositions(str):
    positions = []
    currentPosition = 0
    for c in str:
        if c.isupper():
            positions.append(currentPosition)
        currentPosition += 1
    return positions

print(getUpperPositions("HaH"))
```

Comment: use `enumerate` don't keep a `current_position` variable manually

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think it's beyond the knowledge of OP

Comment: ... well it's a perfect time to learn. It's a pretty basic python iterator, and anyway, if you are dipping into `re` you should definitely already know about `enumerate`. Also, you should really use the `islower` method.

Answer (score 0):

With `re.finditer()` function:

```
import re

s = ' ..HaH soME text heRe ...'
upper_pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'[A-Z]', s)]
print(upper_pos)
```

The output:

```
[3, 5, 9, 10, 19]
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.finditer

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution:

```
output = []
for i in range(text):
    if text[i].upper() == text[1]:
        output.append(i)
print(output)
```

I think that will work. It might not be the best way but it was the first idea that came into my head.

Comment: `text[1]`? Why always refer to that character in the text?

Comment: How do you initialize `text`? Your code does not work if I use a string like `text="HaH"`

Comment: @ThomasWeller text is to be filled with whatever string you are using and it is `text[i]` not `text[1]`